# How to generate an uneven sequence of numbers in R

Tags: r, sequence

Here's an example data frame:

```
df <- data.frame(x=c(1,1,2,2,2,3,3,4,5,6,6,6,9,9),y=c(1,2,3,4,6,3,7,8,6,4,3,7,3,2))
```

I want to generate a sequence of numbers according to the number of observations of `y` per `x` group (e.g. there are 2 observations of `y` for `x=1`). I want the sequence to be continuously increasing and jumps by 2 after each `x` group.

The desired output for this example would be:

```
1,2,5,6,7,10,11,14,17,20,21,22,25,26
```

How can I do this simply in R?

Comment: If they're grouped already, and labelled in the way you have shown, couldn't you just run it as `df$rowname <- 1:dim(df)[1];df$newNumber <- df$rowname + (df$x-1)*2`, and `df$newNumber` will be the desired output?

Comment: @chappers thanks for the idea, however I'm looking for a general solution, I just realized that my x is sequential, which can be solved by this, but x can really be any value

Comment: Extending @chappers idea, `library(data.table); setDT(df)[, gr:= .GRP, x][, 1:.N + (gr-1)*2]#[1]  1  2  5  6  7 10 11 14 17 20 21 22 25 26`

Comment: @xyy it doesn't actually matter as you can just convert a factor to numeric...

Comment: Or using `base R`, `(with(df, match(x, unique(x)))-1)*2 + 1:nrow(df)`

Comment: @chappers ah I did not even think of that, thank you very much, please do post it as a solution (perhaps include the factor conversion)

Comment: I'm missing something here: do the values of `y` matter at all?  Or do you just "jump" by 2 every time `x` changes value? Because a simple `rle(sort(x))` will give you enough information to do so.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft the values of `y` doesn't matter, how would we make `rle(sort(x))` work in this case?

Comment: @xxy `rle` will return the run length of each value of x. Then just grab each value in the output create a sequence from `value` to the matching `runlength` and add  the current index plus to to that sequence. suppose the third `x` value is `5`  and its corresponding run is `4` long.  since the current index is `3`,  create `(5:8 )+(2*3)`   .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To expand on my comment, the groupings can be arbitrary, you simply need to recast it to the correct ordering. There are a few ways to do this, @akrun has shown that this can be accomplished using `match` function, or you can make use the the `as.numeric` function if this is easier to understand for yourself.

```
df <- data.frame(x=c(1,1,2,2,2,3,3,4,5,6,6,6,9,9),y=c(1,2,3,4,6,3,7,8,6,4,3,7,3,2))

# these are equivalent
df$newx <- as.numeric(factor(df$x, levels=unique(df$x)))
df$newx <- match(df$x, unique(df$x))
```

Since you now have a "new" releveling which is sequential, we can use the logic that was discussed in the comments.

```
df$newNumber <- 1:nrow(df) + (df$newx-1)*2
```

For this example, this will result in the following dataframe:

```
x y newx newNumber
1 1    1         1
1 2    1         2
2 3    2         5
2 4    2         6
2 6    2         7
3 3    3        10
3 7    3        11
4 8    4        14
5 6    5        17
6 4    6        20
6 3    6        21
6 7    6        22
9 3    7        25
9 2    7        26
```

where `df$newNumber` is the output you wanted.

---

To create the sequence `0,0,4,4,4,9,...`, basically what you're doing is taking the minimum of each group and subtracting `1`. The easiest way to do this is using the `library(dplyr)`.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(x) %>%
  mutate(newNumber2 = min(newNumber) -1)
```

Which will have the output:

```
Source: local data frame [14 x 5]
Groups: x

   x y newx newNumber newNumber2
1  1 1    1         1          0
2  1 2    1         2          0
3  2 3    2         5          4
4  2 4    2         6          4
5  2 6    2         7          4
6  3 3    3        10          9
7  3 7    3        11          9
8  4 8    4        14         13
9  5 6    5        17         16
10 6 4    6        20         19
11 6 3    6        21         19
12 6 7    6        22         19
13 9 3    7        25         24
14 9 2    7        26         24
```

Comment: thank you chappers! I'm wondering if you'd have some other genius way of getting the sequence `0,0,4,4,4,9,9,13,16,19,19,19,24,24` from the same data as above?

Comment: See my edit. There might be a way to do it in Base R, but dplyr was my initial thought.